# How to use Syntax Highlighting GitBook

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, gitbook

I'm new to GitBook and I am trying to make the syntax highlight work as expected for some JavaScript lines of code.

---

[image: some javascript lines without colour]

---

I noticed that there is a plugin store in the editor. I enabled a plugin called `highlight` but it's not doing it's job.

I searched in the documentation for this, but [I couldn't find anything related](https://help.gitbook.com/?q=highlight).

This book has the syntax highlighting enabled and working:
https://gitbookio.gitbooks.io/javascript/content/basics/comments.html

**book.json**

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "highlight"
    ],
    "pluginsConfig": {}
}
```

How can I do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing GitBook pages in Markdown, you can highlight your code like below:

````
```javascript
var foo = function(num) {
    return num + num;
}
```
````

Where 'javascript' can be replaced with other languages, such as 'python', 'java', 'c' etc.

Answer (score 2):

I did my research and I found out how to do this.

I tried another plugin called [`Ace`](https://github.com/ymcatar/gitbook-plugin-ace). This plugin worked, here is my **book.json**

```
{
    "plugins": ["ace"],
    "pluginsConfig": {
    }
}
```

And I needed to nest the block of code with a basic syntax for JavaScript.

**Input.**

```
## The Arrow function
Now this should be syntax highlighted
In ES5

{%ace edit=false, lang='javascript', check=false, theme="tomorrow" %}
var myFunction = function(num) {  
    return num + num;
};
{%endace%}

In ES6

{%ace edit=false, lang='javascript', check=false, theme="tomorrow" %}
let myFunction = (num) => num + num;
{%endace%}
```

**Output.**

[image: code highlighted]

This is working just fine!